# 3D Positional Audio – Move SCNAudioPlayer along Y and Z Axis

Tags: swift, macos, scenekit, scnaudioplayer

Using SceneKit, I can move audioNode from left to right on x axis, but I'm having problem moving on y and z axis. I'm wearing headphone, so I can hear the binaural (3d audio) effects. Also I'm running this on MacOS.

My testing code is below. Could someone let me know what I'm missing? I'd appreciate it!

```
import Cocoa
import SceneKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: SCNView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Sounds/Test.mp3", 
                                         ofType: nil)

        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        let source = SCNAudioSource(url:url)!
        source.loops = true
        source.shouldStream = false
        source.isPositional = true
        source.load()

        let player = SCNAudioPlayer(source: source)
        let box = SCNBox(width: 100.0, 
                        height: 100.0, 
                        length: 100.0, 
                 chamferRadius: 100.0)
        let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
        let audioNode = SCNNode()
        boxNode.addChildNode(audioNode)

        let scene = SCNScene()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
        sceneView.scene = scene
        audioNode.addAudioPlayer(player)

        let avm = player.audioNode as! AVAudioMixing
        avm.volume = 1.0
        let up = SCNAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 100, z: 0, duration: 5)
        let down = SCNAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -100, z: 0, duration: 5)
        let sequence = SCNAction.sequence([up, down])
        let loop = SCNAction.repeatForever(sequence)
        boxNode.runAction(loop)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After researching and experimenting for a hwile, I finally figured it out. There were two things that I needed to fix.

1. I had to change the default renderingAlgorithm for SCNAudioPlayer.AVAudioNode from equalPowerPanning to either HRTF or HRTFHQ. However, AVAudioNode does not have renderingAlgorithm property. However, I was able to cast SCNAudioPlayer.AVAudioNode as AVAudioPlayerNode, and AVAudioPlayerNode does have renderingAlgorithm property. Here's the relevant code.

```
if let apn = player.audioNode as? AVAudioPlayerNode {
    apn.renderingAlgorithm = .HRTFHQ
}
```

2. I had to assign a node with SCNCamera to pointOfView for SCNView. Also I had to change the position of the camera node further away from the audioNode. Otherwise, I heard the drastic movement in the beginning. Here's the relevant code.

```
let cameraNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width:1, height:1, length:1, chamferRadius: 0.1))
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -10)
sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode
```

My scene.rootNode is a box geometry with 100x100x100 dimension. Inside scene.rootNode, I have a boxNode with 50x5050 dimension. Then inside the boxNode, I have audioNode generating sound with 1x1x1 dimension as well as cameraNode with 1x1x1 dimension. AudioNode's start position is 0,0,0, and the position for the cameraNode is 0,0,-20.

Finally here's the entire working code.

import Cocoa
import AVFoundation
import SceneKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: SCNView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Sounds/Test_mono.mp3", ofType: nil)
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    let source = SCNAudioSource(url: url)!
    source.loops = true
    source.shouldStream = false
    source.isPositional = true
    source.load()
    let player = SCNAudioPlayer(source: source)
    if let apn = player.audioNode as? AVAudioPlayerNode {
        apn.renderingAlgorithm = .HRTFHQ
    }

    let audioNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width:1, height:1, length:1, chamferRadius: 0.1))
    let cameraNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width:1, height:1, length:1, chamferRadius: 0.1))
```

cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width:50, height:50, length:50, chamferRadius: 1))
        boxNode.addChildNode(audioNode)
        audioNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
        boxNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -10)

```
    let scene = SCNScene()
    scene.rootNode.geometry = SCNBox(width:100, height:100, length:100, chamferRadius: 0.1)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
```

boxNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)

```
    sceneView.scene = scene
    sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode
    sceneView.audioListener = cameraNode

    audioNode.addAudioPlayer(player)
    let move = SCNAction.moveBy(x:1, y:0, z:0, duration: 1)
    let sequence = SCNAction.sequence([move])
    let loop = SCNAction.repeatForever(sequence)
    audioNode.runAction(loop)
```

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

```
override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**.

You're casting the `player.audioNode` to `AVAudioMixing` protocol:

```
let avm = player.audioNode as! AVAudioMixing
```

But instead of it, you have to cast it to a class. A code looks like this:

```
let avm = player.audioNode as? AVAudioEnvironmentNode
```

> Any node that conforms to the `AVAudioMixing` protocol (for example, `AVAudioPlayerNode`) can act as a source in this environment. The environment has an implicit `listener`. By controlling the listener’s position and orientation, the application controls the way the user experiences the virtual world. This node also defines properties for distance attenuation and reverberation that help characterize the environment.

[And take into account](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioenvironmentnode) !

> Only inputs with a mono channel connection format to the environment node are spatialized. **`If the input is stereo, the audio is passed through without being spatialized`**. Inputs with connection formats of more than two channels aren't supported.

**And, of course, you need to implement [AVAudio3DMixing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudio3dmixing) protocol**.

## Here's a working code:

```
import SceneKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: NSViewController, AVAudio3DMixing {

    // YOU NEED MONO AUDIO !!!

    var renderingAlgorithm = AVAudio3DMixingRenderingAlgorithm.sphericalHead
    var rate: Float = 0.0
    var reverbBlend: Float = 0.5
    var obstruction: Float = -100.0
    var occlusion: Float = -100.0
    var position: AVAudio3DPoint = AVAudio3DPoint(x: 0, y: 0, z: -100)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()            
        let scene = SCNScene()

        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.camera?.zFar = 200
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 40)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView
        sceneView.scene = scene
        sceneView.backgroundColor = NSColor.black
        sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Test_Mono", ofType: "mp3")
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        let source = SCNAudioSource(url: url)!
        source.loops = true
        source.shouldStream = false  // MUST BE FALSE
        source.isPositional = true
        source.load()

        let player = SCNAudioPlayer(source: source)
        let audioNode = SCNNode()

        let box = SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0.2)
        let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)

        boxNode.addChildNode(audioNode)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

        audioNode.addAudioPlayer(player)
        let avm = player.audioNode as? AVAudioEnvironmentNode
        avm?.reverbBlend = reverbBlend
        avm?.renderingAlgorithm = renderingAlgorithm
        avm?.occlusion = occlusion
        avm?.obstruction = obstruction

        let up = SCNAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 0, z: 70, duration: 5)
        let down = SCNAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 0, z: -70 , duration: 5)
        let sequence = SCNAction.sequence([up, down])
        let loop = SCNAction.repeatForever(sequence)
        boxNode.runAction(loop)

        avm?.position = AVAudio3DPoint(
                 x: Float(boxNode.position.x),
                 y: Float(boxNode.position.y),
                 z: Float(boxNode.position.z))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, if I change the line you pointed out, I get "Could not cast value of type AVAudioPlayerNode to AVAudioEnvironmentNode".

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: thanks again. It seems the environment reverb is either off or very low, so you can't really hear the spatial depth despite volume changes. Also "let avm = player.audioNode as? AVAudioMixerNode" results in nil, so all the avm?... statements don't seem to work. I tried to modify sceneView.audioEnvironmentNode.reverbParameters.loadFactoryReverbPreset( .largeHall), but sceneView.audioEnvironmentNode returns nil. Then I tried to make my own AVAudioEnvironmentNode and assign it to sceneView.audioEnvironmentNode, but it says it's not mutable. How can I modify reverb for the scene?

Comment: Reverb is another issue, so it's another question)). Let's follow SO rules. And if you find my answer useful, please accept it.

Comment: No problem. I'll create a separate question. However, would you mind fixing the two lines for other people? `let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView` This fails because can't cast from NSViewController to SCNView. I added SCNView to storyboard and created `@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: SCNView!` Also `let avm = player.audioNode as? AVAudioMixerNode` results in nil when you actually try to access it without optional chaining because it says AVAudioPlayerNode can't be casted to AVAudioMixerNode. Thanks!

Comment: `let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView` works fine, don't know why you got fail.